# Deleteing record from table in mySQL database with PDO

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I have been trying to delete a row from my data base but it keep showing me deleted without deleting anything please can someone figure out what the problem is with my codes

I have tried using PDO and mysql but is not deleting but will show deleted 
I don't know what to do again.

**MYSQL**

```
    if($user == $me){
        $sql_delete = "DELETE FROM replys WHERE id = '$id' AND rusername = '$me'";
        echo $sql_delete;
        mysql_query($sql_delete) or die(mysql_error());
        echo "Deleted";
    }
    else{
    }
}
?>
```

**PDO**

```
<?php
session_start();  
if(isset($_POST['DeleteThis'])){

    $db_host = "localhost";
    $db_user = "root";
    $db_pass = "kindom";
    $db_name = "posters";

    try {
        $user = $_SESSION['username'];
        $form = $_POST;
        $id = $form['id']);
        $me = $form['me'];
        if($me == $user){
            $db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}",$db_user,$db_pass);
            $db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $stmt = $db_conn->prepare("DELETE FROM replys WHERE id = :id AND rusername = :user");

//I have tried using this SQL statements  
//$query = "DELETE FROM replys WHERE id = {$id} AND rusername = {$user}"; 
//$query = "DELETE * FROM replys WHERE id = :id AND rusername = :rusername"; 
            $query = "DELETE FROM replys WHERE id = :id AND rusername = :rusername"; 

            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id); 
            $stmt->bindParam(':rusername', $user);

            $stmt->execute();
            echo "Deleted";
        }
        else{
            //Do nothing
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Error:" . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $db_conn = null;
}
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('deleterp').submit();"><i style="font-size:17px;color:#F00;" class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
<form id="deleterp" action="" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $rpId;?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="DeleteThis" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="me" value="<?php echo $rplyuser;?>"/>
</form></div>
```

Comment: the delete query didn't get prepared? and the statement as Fred mentioned.

Comment: Look at this very carefully `DELETE replys` and compare it to what the manuals states http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/delete.html and as @MarkNg stated, read the manual http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: @MarkNg if it ever makes it there. ^ see above ;-) we both edited.

Comment: a bit surprised that `$db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` didn't throw an exception, however my thoughts on this are that, it doesn't because it never gets prepared.

Comment: @MarkNg is my error when posting the question

Comment: you also had this in commented `DELETE *` which is invalid syntax. Do read the links given for the manuals. and now you have all DELETEs commented out. check for errors besides the PDO - http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php that `$_SESSION['username']` may be empty/not set.

Comment: He is confused. Previously he wrote in question `DELETE replys ` iin **PDO** section. Now, he edited to `DELETE FROM replys `..

Comment: Please is my error while i was typing the question because i deleted the PDO program and try my sql now i have edited my question please guys

Comment: So now you sure the code now is correct? have you run it and test if there is any error? 
@ Fred, was thinking, since he managed to echo "Deleted"... hmmm...the statement says rusername = :user but bindParam is ':rusername'... ... I suggest you read the manual first, link is as @Fred-ii- has posted above. I am too puzzled why there is no exception thrown

Comment: and PDO error would have thrown you something to the effect of unmatched binding, once it ever gets there.

Comment: @MarkNg About not throwing an exception for their issue is similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/35020308/ where Riggs and I both posted an answer about recently. So that may very be the same case here. My answer was more of an educated guess before going in-depth into the manuals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PDO**

Change

```
$stmt = $db_conn->prepare("DELETE FROM replys WHERE id = :id AND rusername = :rusername");
```

to

```
$stmt = $db_conn->prepare("DELETE FROM replys WHERE id = :id AND rusername = :user");
```

Like ..

```
<?php
.
.
$stmt = $db_conn->prepare("DELETE FROM replys WHERE id = :id AND rusername = :rusername");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id); 
$stmt->bindParam(':rusername', $user);
.
.
?>
```

Change

```
$id = $form['id']);
```

to

```
$id = $form['id'];
```

for not getting

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in
>   /home/umu35534/public_html/questions.php on line 70

Comment: I'm getting this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in /home/umu35534/public_html/questions.php on line 70`

Comment: Which line is 70 @Codesoft ?

Comment: Good catch on the `Change

$id = $form['id']);

to

$id = $form['id'];`.

Comment: I also don't know sir

Comment: *I also don't know sir...* But, we know. Check my edited answer @Codesoft.

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii- `:)`

Comment: @NanaPartykar welcome.

Comment: Yes i did and the error cleared but not delete

Comment: Whatever changes i told you to do. You did or not ? You used `$stmt->execute();` this line or not. Your code was having extra `)`. So, i can predict you are doing some silly mistake there. We don't know your database. We can help you in correcting the syntax. So, you have to check it properly whether you are using correct table name, column name .. @Codesoft

Comment: Okay i will check every error @NanaPartykar